# How do I install the latest Sun Java JRE on Ubuntu Server 9.10?

Tags: java, ubuntu, aptitude

Unfortunately, if I try to install sun-java via apt-get, it's not found in the repositories.

```
# apt-get install sun-java6-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sun-java6-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package sun-java6-jre has no installation candidate
```

If I try to install it using the bin from Sun's website, here's the issue:

```
# ./jre-6u18-linux-i586.bin
(license agreement...)
Do you agree to the above license terms? [yes or no]
yes 
Unpacking...
Checksumming...
Extracting...
./jre-6u18-linux-i586.bin: 366: ./install.sfx.10648: not found
Failed to extract the files.  Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of
the Installation Instructions on the download page for more information.
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the multiverse repository in Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu